# DexArchiveMergerException Program type already present: a.a.a

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I am getting this exception:

> AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Program type already present:
>   a.a.a","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives:  Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   Program type already present: a.a.a   at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:131)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:118)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:444)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:335)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:39)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:105)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$1.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:99)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to
>   complete  at com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:55)  at
>   com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)  at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:116)
>     ... 30 more Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException:
>   Error: Program type already present: a.a.a    at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:21)    at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.a(:7)     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.t.a(:36)   ... 32 more
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexProdRelease'.
>
>   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
>   >     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
>   >      Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>   >      Program type already present: a.a.a

I am not sure what this file mean lot alot of search but failed to create build.

I am using the following dependencies:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlibjdk7:1.3.50'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.2.0-alpha03'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0-alpha03'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams:2.2.0-alpha03'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.5.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.11.0'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:2.3.0'

implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:1.5.0'

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'

implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'

implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:18.0.0'

implementation 'io.card:android-sdk:5.5.1'

implementation 'com.localytics.android:library:5.6.1'

implementation 'net.zetetic:android-database-sqlcipher:4.0.1@aar'

implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'


implementation 'com.adobe.mobile:adobeMobileLibrary:4.13.7'

implementation 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:5.22.1'

implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha03'

implementation 'androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha03'

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01'

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:16.0.0'

implementation(project(':SA')) {      transitive = true   }

implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'

implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0'

implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'

annotationProcessor 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0'

implementation 'com.jaeger.statusbarutil:library:1.4.0'

implementation 'com.sasank.roundedhorizontalprogress:roundedhorizontalprogress:1.0.1'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.19.0'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:21.0.0'

implementation 'me.saket:better-link-movement-method:2.2.0'

implementation 'com.tbuonomo.andrui:viewpagerdotsindicator:4.0'

implementation 'com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.11.0'`
```

So I have updated this:
 `implementation(project(':SA')) {transitive = true   }`

to `implementation files('libs/SA.aar')`

Now I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class a.a.a found in modules classes.jar (SA.aar) and classes.jar (com.google.ar:core:1.12.0)
  Duplicate class a.a.b found in modules classes.jar (SA.aar) and classes.jar (com.google.ar:core:1.12.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.a.a.a found in modules classes.jar (SA.aar) and classes.jar (com.google.ar:core:1.12.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.a.a.b found in modules classes.jar (SA.aar) and classes.jar (com.google.ar:core:1.12.0)
```

How should I resolve this?

Comment: Is your resolved the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

So you have an obfuscated build here, try disabling this obfuscation first and see if the issue persists.

If it persists it is likely showing you the actual dangling class, which - most of the time - points you to one or more libraries that depend on a conflicting 3rd party dependency, in which case you'd simply `exclude` that dependency from being included transitively into your build.

If it does not persist in a non-obfuscated build, check your symbols file to get the name of the class / program type `a.a.a` was obfuscated to. This file usually resides somewhere underneath `app/build/outputs/**/mapping.txt`.

It might also totally be a temporary issue, in this case make a clean build and try again.

Comment: so i am using    implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.11.0" the debug build is fine but when its goes to production i am getting conflicts  a.a.a the obfuscation   is from dependencies  and i am unable to find this a.a.a can u please explain how should i get a.a.a file

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your build.gradle file it looks you have added **legacy** library and your **SA module** twice

```
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation(project(':SA')) {transitive = true}
```

**The culprit is the second one.**

Maybe that can be the your issue as the error says about duplicates.

Trying **removing** the same or maybe you **dont** need that **legacy library** itself I think.

Because sometimes it gets added in my build.gradle **automatically** and I have to remove that manually.

Answer (score 0):

I faced problem like this and

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

helped me